# Unable to allow row selection on click over mshflexgrid control in vb6

Tags: vb6

The form that has mshflexgrid control is not allowing to select the row on which the mouse click has done. Sometimes it allows selection of previous row and not the row which is been clicked

I have tried adding one to the property .RowSel of mshflexgrid to allow the row selection, it is not working for second row selection.

```
Private Sub MSHFlexGrid1_Click()
    last_row_selected = MSHFlexGrid1.RowSel
    If last_row_selected <> 1 Then last_row_selected = last_row_selected + 1
    With MSHFlexGrid1
        If (boolShift And vbShiftMask) = vbShiftMask Then
            SelectionOneAfterTheOther
        ElseIf (boolShift And vbCtrlMask) = vbCtrlMask Then
            SelectUnSelectGridRow
        Else
            UnSelectAllGridRows
            .Row = last_row_selected
            .ColSel = .Cols - 1
            .CellBackColor = vbHighlight
            .CellForeColor = vbHighlightText
        End If
    End With
    MSHFlexGrid1.Refresh
End Sub
```

It seems that the .RowSel property isn't taking correct value for selection of row
The result needs to be proper selection of row on which it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your grid Click event, try something like this:

```
With MSHFlexGrid1
    If .Row = .RowSel Then
        .Col = .Cols - 1
        .ColSel = 0
    End If
End With
```

You may need to set SelectionMode on the grid control also.  The above code should work if set to flexSelectionFree

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `SelectionMode` property? If not, you get to it by clicking "Custom" in the properties window. This opens a dialog where `SelectionMode` is one of the available properties.[image]